# How can I debug PHP cURL not triggering a request?

Tags: php, laravel, http, curl, request

## Environment

- PHP Version : **PHP 5.6.21**
- cURL Version : **curl 7.29.0**
- Web Server : **Nginx**
- Linux : **Cent OS**

---

## Description

I have this CURL in PHP.

```
$headers = array(
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Authorization: Basic " . $auth_code
);

$data = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$code;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$AUTH_TOKEN_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I did a Wireshark capture, I **don't** any GET/POST requests initiating.

What could possibly prevent it?

What else should I look into?

I've tried print out these 2 values

```
**dd($ch);**
```

I got

```
"ch" => curl resource @10 ▼
    url: "https://www.web.com/oauth"
    content_type: null
    http_code: 0
    header_size: 0
    request_size: 0
    filetime: -1
    ssl_verify_result: 0
    redirect_count: 0
    total_time: 0.004216
    namelookup_time: 0.004148
    connect_time: 0.113475
    pretransfer_time: 0.0
    size_upload: 0.0
    size_download: 0.0
    speed_download: 0.0
    speed_upload: 0.0
    download_content_length: -1.0
    upload_content_length: -1.0
    starttransfer_time: 0.0
    redirect_time: 0.0
    redirect_url: ""
    primary_ip: "8.8.8.8"
    certinfo: []
    primary_port: 443
    local_ip: "10.0.129.127"
    local_port: 56907
}
```

With:

```
**dd($info);**
```

I got

```
"info" => array:26 [▼
"url" => "https://www.web.com/oauth"
"content_type" => null
"http_code" => 0
"header_size" => 0
"request_size" => 0
"filetime" => 0
"ssl_verify_result" => 0
"redirect_count" => 0
"total_time" => 0.0
"namelookup_time" => 0.0
"connect_time" => 0.0
"pretransfer_time" => 0.0
"size_upload" => 0.0
"size_download" => 0.0
"speed_download" => 0.0
"speed_upload" => 0.0
"download_content_length" => -1.0
"upload_content_length" => -1.0
"starttransfer_time" => 0.0
"redirect_time" => 0.0
"redirect_url" => ""
"primary_ip" => ""
"certinfo" => []
"primary_port" => 0
"local_ip" => ""
"local_port" => 0
]
```

nothing seems to use in there.

Comment: Did you check the web server and system logs?

Comment: nginx logs ? or cent OS log ?

Comment: "and" implies both.

Comment: have you made sure curl is enabled on the server?

Comment: @DavidVanDeMeer - yes. I have. But how to make sure to be 100% ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I know the path the nginx error log, but what is the path for sys logs, I should look into ?

Comment: `/var/log/nginx/error.log` + 
`/var/log/nginx/access.log`

Comment: Either in `/var/log/messages` or via `journalctl` depending on the version of CentOS.

Comment: Ok, I will look into this : `/var/log/messages` also. Thanks

Comment: Create a PHP INFO file phpinfo.php with content below and on the server and load it on the browser - then search that info for curl
`<?php 
phpinfo(); 
?>`

Comment: I run `curl loclahost`, it loaded my signin page. Is that good enough ? It proof that my curl cli is working.

Comment: [Php - Debugging Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/3226121) - you can save curl error into the file. Look at `$verbose = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux is preventing the httpd process from making a network connection.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

See the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page for details.

Comment: Is there any VM or linux details that I can share with u ?

Comment: `/var/log/messages` - is empty.

Comment: `/var/log/nginx/access.log` - is empty

Comment: Do I need to restart any kind of service after running your suggestion `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` ???

Answer (score 1):

You could try `strace` if you need some further investigation.

If this code is triggered for example by visiting the page '/mycode.php':

```
strace -tt -e trace=sendto,connect,open,write,read php /path/to/your/app/mycode.php
```

If your code is executed through a framework or handled though an entry point such as index.php:

```
HTTP_HOST=www.yourdomain.com REQUEST_URI=/mycode.php strace -tt -e trace=sendto,connect,open,write,read php /path/to/your/app/index.php
```

The output from this should be able to point you towards the source of the issue (eg, certain files not opening, proccesses not starting)